# Ajax call with works only twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

I have a strange one.

I have a div which has an onclick event, calling a function, which in turn makes an ajax call.
Doing so in Safari works exactly twice.
Running the same program with an iPhone works perfectly every time.

This is is what I am doing:

```
// this is created by the Ajax call
no1 = 0;
no2 = 1;
formName = "myButton" + no1 + no2;
//newItem is what is returned by the Ajax call
newItem = "<div id=\"trainingOptions\" onclick=\"request_ajax('".$formName."')\">";
//this places the onclick event into the HTML code
document.getElementById.("myDiv").innerHTML = newItem;
```

So basically this is how the onclick event is placed over and over again.
This part is replaced with exactly the same, when request_ajax answers.

Now this works exactly two times in Safari and as often as clicked on the iPhone.

Any ideas why this happens?

Best Kurt

Comment: maybe you have online example? not jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving very few elements for us to help you. So this is just a guess which is the following:

Your appending:

```
newItem = "<div id=\"trainingOptions\" onclick=\"request_ajax('".$formName."')\">";
```

As you are not clearing the div before you append it, it seems to me that you are appending multiple divs with the same id. As browsers handle multiple equivalent IDs in different ways, this is what might be causing you your problem.

There should only be one element with one ID, you can't have two elements with the same ID this can cause conflicts. So maybe that's what is happening to you.

Comment: I will check on that one. Thanks for that guess